# Bash How to convert a date into a variable in another format

Tags: bash

I try to do this below but I have an error, date: invalid date '10/04/2019'

```
#Ask for the date to search
#echo "Date to look for dd/mm/yyyy"
read -p "Date to look for:" InitDate
echo $InitDate

#convert the date to yyyy-mm-dd
InitDate1=$(date -d $InitDate '+%Y%m%d')
echo $InitDate1
```

How to transform 10/04/2019 to 20190419 in the variable.

Answer (score 2):

GNU's `date` utility is a little strange, it's `--date` argument accepts all kinds of strange inputs, and doesn't accepts all kinds of "looking ok" inputs.

From `man date`:

```
The --date=STRING is a mostly free format human readable date string
such as "Sun, 29 Feb 2004 16:21:42 -0800" or "2004-02-29 16:21:42" or
 even "next Thursday". ...
```

And try to use only that format. In your case, I would do:

```
IFS='/' read -r day mon year <<<"$InitDate"
InitDate1=$(date --date "$year-$month-$day 00:00:00" '+%Y%m%d')
```

You can also extract the `day`, `mon` and `year` path using for example bash substrings, like ex. `day=${InitDate:1:4} mon=${InitDate:5:2} year=${InitDate:7:2}`

But as you already have the date in `yyyy`,  `mm` and `dd` format, there is little need in using `date` at all. Just:

```
IFS='/' read -r day mon year <<<"$InitDate"
echo "$year$mon$day"
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you are trying to do is to rearrange day/month/year in the string you have, this is easily done with string manipulation.  For instance:

```
echo '10/04/2019' | sed -E 's/([0-9]+)\/([0-9]+)\/([0-9]+)/\3\2\1/'
```

If you do need it imported to the `date` utility (for more advanced conversions like into seconds since epoch), you should take a look at your man pages because the implementation varies depending on the system.

Comment: I disagree with this approach. Date/Time is complex enough without dragging in regular expressions.

Comment: I appreciate your point.  Working with time is complex, but the op isn't actually doing anything with the date other than rearranging some numbers in a string.  If you are working in bash I think a simple regex is less complex and more portable.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help.

I've done this:

```
<code>
#!/bin/sh
#ask the date
read -p "Date a rechercher:" InitDate
#conversion
InitDate1=$(echo $InitDate | sed -E 's/([0-9]+)\/([0-9]+)\/([0-9]+)/\3-\2-\1/')
echo $InitDate1
InitDate2=$(echo $InitDate | sed -E 's/([0-9]+)\/([0-9]+)\/([0-9]+)/\3\2\1/')
echo $InitDate2
</code>
```

Nicolas